# Drop duplicates for each partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

origin data

```
cls, id  
----
a, 1
a, 1
----
b, 3
b, 3
b, 4
```

expected output

```
cls, id  
----
a, 1
----
b, 3
b, 4
```

id can be duplicates only in same cls, It means same id do not exist across clses.

In that case.

```
df.dropDuplicates($id)
```

will shuffle across all partitions to check duplicates over cls. and repartitioned to 200(default value)

Now, How can I run dropDuplicates for each partition seperately to reduce computing cost?

something like

```
df.foreachPartition(_.dropDuplicates())
```

Comment: can you put the excepted output for this input in question

Comment: Please see what I added to the question. expected data updated.

Comment: if you have only these 2 values then can you try `distinct()` method

Comment: is distinct() not just an alias of dropDuplicates()? https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#distinct()

Comment: ah, actually there 10 more fields, but id field is hash of the whole row so it can be used for dropDuplicates($id). but other 10 fields also required after dropDuplicates().

Comment: i think you should try this `df.dropDublicates("cls", "id")` this will remove the duplicated if id and cls are same

Comment: How to decide which row can be drop if there are more than 2 columns which you need later(drop the first (a,1) or the lastest (a,1))

Comment: @AkashSethi but df.dropDublicates("cls", "id") will shuffle over all partions then repartitioned. I want not to shuffled over partition.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably after something like this:

```
val distinct = df.mapPartitions(it => {
    val set = Set();
    while (it.hasNext) {
        set += it.next()
    }
    return set.iterator
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not not a with set.  In fact Set is too dangerous if the size of the data is huge.
One option that you can think of is adding mapPartitionsWithIndex and add the index as an output iterator.  This way in your DF, the partition index exist.  Later, apply drop duplicates by passing partition number and the other key.  Ideally, for the combination of the key and map partition the duplicate records get removed.