# Dataframe dropduplicate in partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 1billion rows dataframe.
schema is

```
--------------------------
action_id , hash , user_no
--------------------------
click , go4grf , 1
click , ferfg43 , 2
view  , erioer , 3
view  , erioer , 3
view  , oijnvio , 4
... many many rows...
```

Now I want to dropduplicates based on hash column.

```scala
df.dropDuplicates(Seq("hash"))
```

This will drop duplicates well.

But Is is not efficient because hash value only can be duplicate in same action_id. It will shuffle all data across executors.

So I imagine, If I can drop duplicate within each partition it will be good for performance.

Something like..

```scala
dataframeList = df.splitByColumnValue("action_id")
// split dataframe into multiple dataframes by some field's value

deduplicatedDf = dataframeList.foreach(df => df.dropDuplicates("hash")).join()
// dropDuplicates for each dataframes then join it to one df.
```

I know this is not a spark code. but any body know how can do something like above in spark scala api?

Comment: can you try group By on `action_id` and then drop duplicate from `hash`

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290248/drop-duplicates-for-each-partition? Isn't it your question as well ? Aren't you doing the same there here too ?

Comment: right, That is my question too. but to now I can not find a straightfoward solution.

Comment: The issue is that you haven't accepted that answer nor commented on why it's not working for you. Which makes this a duplicate question

Comment: I couldn't accept answer because the single answer didn't help at all, and discussed by comment on the question.

Comment: Then you edit your question. You can't post the same question twice.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry for the duplication. I'll keep this in mind from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can drop duplicate within each partition it will be good for performance.

Performance aside it won't resolve your problem. Unless you can ensure that data is partitioned by `action_id` (this usually requires preceding shuffle) you'll still need a full shuffle to remove duplicates.

If shuffle is not crucial `dropDuplicates` is already close to optimal. If you analyze execution plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
SortAggregate(key=[hash#48], functions=[first(action_id#47, false), first(user_no#49, false)])
+- *Sort [hash#48 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(hash#48, 200)
      +- SortAggregate(key=[hash#48], functions=[partial_first(action_id#47, false), partial_first(user_no#49, false)])
         +- *Sort [hash#48 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- LocalTableScan [action_id#47, hash#48, user_no#49]
```

you'll see that it applies local dedupilcation (`partial_first`) and can use sorting based approach.